# Problem installing ArchLinux on LVM on a LUKS setup via archboot

Tags: arch-linux, luks, lvm, dm-crypt

I've used archlinux before, and I've decided to have it enccrypted. I use BIOS. I used the latest vesion of archboot. I made an LUKS setup, then made lvm volume group and two ext4 partition in it for / and /boot. Then I made a ext4 boot partition and let the setup to save the password in my root partition and use kernel path for fstab.

After the installation I corrected my fstab and mkintcpio and once installed syslinux and the other time grub.  But no matter what the bootloader is it couldn't load the OS or the and goes to rootfs without asking the password to my luks setup.

How should I fix it, How much more information is my question lacking to be answered, where am I doing it wrong? I also played with the crypttab however it resulted in no good.

Comment: Does your `HOOKS`-array in `/etc/mkinitcpio.conf` contain these items in this exact order: `encrypt lvm2 filesystems`? And remember, if you edit `/etc/mkinitcpio.conf`, you have to recreate initramfs with this command: `mkinitcpio -p linux`. And does your kernel commandline (`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX`-variable in `/etc/default/grub`) contain this: `cryptdevice=<device>:<dmname>` where `<device>` is the encrypted partion, for example `/dev/sda2` and `<dmname>` is the name given to lvm device which is under `/dev/mapper/<dmname>` , f.ex. `cryptroot`?

Comment: Yes I've done them. However still getting the error. Thanks for you response:)

Comment: Well, `cryptdevice=<device>:<dmname>` kernel parameter should make it to prompt for passphrase, so it sounds like there's something wrong with it. You'd try to edit kernel command line when it boots in grub to ensure that the kernel parameter is right.

Comment: From your question I understand that you have the boot partition encripted and inside the LVM volume group. Is that so?

Comment: No it isn't. It's outside of it:)